# Initialize values such that the component appears when JavaScript is disabled

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I have 3 components in website built in [GatsbyJS](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/) (a static-site generator built on React).

One component provides data from an API and passes it down into the wrapped component via the render prop pattern.

```
class FetchData extends React.Component {
    state = {
        contactData: {
            firstName: "",
            lastName: "",
            email: "",
        },
        isLoaded: false,
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        const { email } = this.props;

        fetch("some_api_endpoint")
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(({ firstName, lastName, email }) => {
                this.setState({
                    contactData: {
                        firstName,
                        lastName,
                        email,
                    },
                    isLoaded: true
                });
        });

        // Fallback if API fails
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({
                isLoaded: true,
            });
        }, 1500);
    }

    render() {
        return this.props.children(this.state);
    }
}
```

The InnerForm depends on the `isLoaded` prop to determine whether to show the form or loading icon.

```
class OuterForm extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <FetchData>
                {({ contactData, isLoaded }) => (
                    <InnerForm contactData={contactData} isLoaded={isLoaded} />
                )}
            </FetchData>
        )
    }
}

class InnerForm extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const { isLoaded, contactData } = this.props;

        return isLoaded 
            ? <Form contactData={contactData} />)
            : <LoadingIcon />;
    }
}
```

The problem is when the site is statically built and JS is disabled in the browser, the page is stuck with the loading icon and the form is never displayed.

I believe this has to do with Gatsby building the site with the initial prop and state values each component receives, which in this case statically renders the `LoadingIcon` instead of the form because isLoading is `initialized` as false.

What would be a solution to ensure the form is rendered when JS is disabled without having to defer to the hacky option of initiating the `FetchData` component state to `isLoading: true`?

Comment: IIRC, you have to tell Gatsby how the data should be retrieved for the static building, see e.g. https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/using-gatsby-without-graphql/

Comment: @inyono that would be ideal, but in this case the "FetchData" needs to be done client-side. What FetchData is actually doing is auto-filling the form which depends on the visitor.

Comment: Ah, I see. Another idea: update your state in componentDidMount or componentWillMount (= JS activated, recheck on React docs which of the lifecycle methods won’t be called on the server), so you basically have three cases: noJS = some fallback form, JS but not loaded = loading spinner, JS but loaded = prefilled form